# Two different modules for roboguice

Tags: android-testing, roboguice

I am using `Roboguice` in my app

and I wish to run some tests. However, my test is throwing me `unauthorized` user.
So I want to inject an `authorization` class to my test, that is not present in the production app, and shouldnt be present

How do I configure `2 **different** Roboguice Modules`, to bind with the needed interfaces ?

Comment: Do you mean use two different modules at the same time, or two different modules, but only one is used, depending on some build parameter (such as debug vs. release)?